# How to return a key content from a HashMap in java?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Working on a small project which stores some students' records in a HashMap as database.

```
private HashMap<String, Student> studentDb = new HashMap<String, Student>();
```

My application has a UI which lets the users to choose any string as key record. It can be numbers or letters.Creating each record, creates an objects from another class which keeps information in its fields, but it is not suppose to store the key.

After storing all the data they can request to see all the data has been stored so far. The toSting method from the class which I instantiate my object from, generates the message to be displayed.

At the time of displaying, I need to display the key they chose with the rest of stored data and they may not ask for all of them. The question is, how can I get access to a given record's key? Let's say if I don't want to use key that user should enter at the time of their request. Is there any way to drive it from the HashMap collection?

I hope I could explain my question.
Thank you.

---

Edit:

[image]

This is the output for a request, but the thing is I read the student's Id from the textfield they insert the request which is kind of cheating. I wondered if I can drive it from the collection itself.

Comment: how do you show the value currently? or *The toSting method from the class which I instantiate my object from generates the message to be displayed* could you share this implementaion as well.

Comment: If the key is `String`, there should be no difference between the one in the map and the one used for lookup.

Comment: I display the the result in JOptionPane.showMessageDialog. It calls the coresponded toString for each object

Comment: You should probably store the ID as part of the `Student` object.

Comment: @shmosel, I can't do that. that has been restricted in the project brief.

Comment: Then it seems perfectly reasonable to print the input as the key.

Comment: @shmosel, I tried to implement .getkey(); method, but it didn't work. I got it from the Oracle's documentation.

Comment: There is no `Map.getKey()` method because it wouldn't make sense to have one. Just use the input, like I said.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use something like this:

Working version:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class test{

    public static void main(String[] args){

        HashMap<String, String> studentDb = new HashMap<String, String>();

        studentDb.put("1","A");
        studentDb.put("2","B");
        studentDb.put("3","C");

        for(String key : studentDb.keySet()){
            System.out.println(studentDb.get(key));
        }

    }
}
```

What you could do for your situation:

```
...

for(String key : studentDb.keySet()){
    if(studentDb.get(key)==/* STUDENT OBJECT */){
        // Display / do something with the key.
    }
}

...
```

Comment: With Java 8 `HashMap<String, String> studentDb = new HashMap<>();`

Comment: Yeah. it worked, but with the if(studentDb.get(key).equals(/* STUDENT OBJECT */)). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean "to drive it from the HashMap collection"?
Your hashmap stores data by key (in this case a String). In order to access a specific value, you need to know its key. If I understand correctly, what you want would be like doing something like :

```
map.get("myKey").getKey();
```

Which doesn't make sense.
What you can do is iterate over all the keys in your map, with the keySet() method. But I'm not sure that's what you were looking for.

Comment: The problem is when I create each object(student) from Student class individually, they don't pass their key to the constructer(That was a restriction in the project brief), so methods of Student class don't have access to the keys including the toStrong method.

Comment: If you have access to the map, then you could always use the entrySet() method and test every entry against your Student.
Something like this : for(Entry<String, Student> entry : map.entrySet()) {
// test entry.getValue().equals(yourStudent)
// if equals then call entry.getKey()
}